# Declaring an SLF4J logger from inside a Scala driver

Tags: scala, reflection, slf4j

I have the following Scala class (`MyApp.scala`):

```
package me.myapp

import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object MyApp {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[MyApp])

  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    logger.info("Well hello SLF4J!")
  }
}
```

When I run this I get a compiler error:

```
/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/src/main/scala/me/myapp/MyApp.scala:7: not found: type MyApp
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[MyApp])
                                               ^
one error found
```

So I need `MyApp` to be an `object` (not a `class`) so that I can have a static `main` method (for my executable JAR), but it seems that, because `MyApp` is an `object`, that `classOf[MyApp]` doesn't actually resolve to anything.

So a few related concerns:

1. Why are `objects` not classes? And if they're not classes then how the heck am I able to get away with putting a `main` method inside of it?!?; and
2. How can I get an SLF4J logger for `MyApp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Objects have indeed a class, but I don't think it's named the object name.
2. Just use LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

Comment: Thanks @C4stor (+1) however when I use `LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)` it produces log messages like: `[main] INFO me.myapp.MyApp$ - Well hello SLF4J!`. Notice that rogue dollar sign ("`$") at the end of the class name? Any way to get rid of it? Thanks again!

Comment: You can use LoggerFactory.getLogger("Any string you want") to customize the displayed name

Comment: I'm guessing the dollar sign is added there because, maybe, Scala treats `object`s as internal/private classes?

Comment: I guess too. I wouldn't dare try explain the internals of the scala compiler (hence my vague answer to point 1) though, but I'm confident enough that it generates more and different classes than what you just code. Probably the case here too :)